# Delete from multiple tables in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, sql-delete

Using MySQL Im trying to delete multiple records at once from multiple tables.
Initially I thought doing something like:

```
DELETE t1, t2
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.table1_id
JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.table1_id
WHERE t1.id IN (?,?,?,?);
```

However, if there are no existing record within table2, would I change the **JOIN** to a **LEFT JOIN**? Also, would doing this cause latency if I were only deleting two or three records across eight tables(2x2x2x2x2x2x2x2)?

Comment: It sounds like you should be using foreign keys with `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Then you just need to delete from t1 and it will automatically delete the related rows in t2 and t3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, changing the join on `table2` to `left join` would do what you want. Rows in `table1` that belong to the list and to `table3` will all get deleted, regardless whether they also exist in `table2`. In the meantime, possible matching rows in `table2` will be deleted too.

```
delete t1, t2
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.table1_id
inner join table3 t3 on t1.id = t3.table1_id
where t1.id in (?, ?, ?, ?);
```

I would suggest rewriting the `join` on `table3` to an `exists` condition instead. This makes the intent of the query more obvious, and might perform better, especially if you have an index on `table3(table1_id)`:

```
delete t1, t2
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.table1_id
where 
    t1.id in (?, ?, ?, ?)
    and exists (select 1 from table3 t3 where t3.table1_id = t1.id)
```